# How to solve this error "Unsupported Node 'item' " in strings.xml

Tags: android

```
  <array name="gender" >
<item>Male</item>
<item>Female</item>
<item>Other</item>
 </array>
```

Would making the items string instead be wise or any other suggestions ( using android studio skill set: novice)

Comment: what are you doing with this xml?

Comment: creating a crud application and this would be the dropdown selection for the user to pick their gender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want `String` arrays:

```
<string-array name="gender" >
   <item>Male</item>
   <item>Female</item>
   <item>Other</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: closing the code with </string-array> or is </array> fine and thank you?